# Delete all files from an array, including some with *

Tags: arrays, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have an array that has a list of various files/folders to delete, including deleting all files in a folder.

```
server_dir="/srv/data/"
removeLocalFiles=("logs/*.log.gz" "plugins/file.txt" "other.txt")
for serverFile in "${removeLocalFiles[@]}"; do
    rm "$server_dir/$serverFile"
done
```

The array would be files, folders, and as you can see, files with a specific extension.

This doesn't work, the files with * doesn't delete.

What can I use to delete all files, in a specific directory? The list would go exactly to that file or folder, so it shouldn't delete anything other then that specific file./

Comment: Why use an array at all, why not `cd "$server_dir" && rm logs/*.log.gz plugins/file.txt other.txt`?

Comment: Do it one shot by storing all files to delete in the array `server_dir="/srv/data"; removeLocalFiles=("${server_dir}"/logs/*.log.gz "${server_dir}/plugins/file.txt" "${server_dir}/other.txt")` and delete as `rm -- "${removeLocalFiles[@]}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your line to test if the directory not empty.If string is not empty rm will work just fine.`[ ! -z "$(ls -A $server_dir/$serverFile")" ] && rm 
"$server_dir/$serverFile"`